# Resources to get started on music theory and arrangement

Tags: theory, piano, learning

Sorry if this is a bad title.

I have been playing the piano for years, mostly classical music, but I would like to focus on other genres now.

I am satisfied with my level of skill if we talk about my technique or how quickly I can learn a new song, but I feel like I am very lacking in music theory.

I know some theory of course. If I listen to someone analyzing the harmony of a song, I would probably be able to understand most of what they say, but I would be completely unable of analyzing it myself.

As of now, I don’t think I can attend any type of lesson, so I would like to learn what I am missing on my own.

My first objective right now would just to be able to look at the chords of a song I know and play to the best of my abilities so that someone can sing along or play other instruments.

Long term objective would be to learn as much as I can about music theory, so that I am able to write music, make covers, analyze songs other people make, maybe even teach this stuff one day?

So, is there any book I could read, videos I could watch, exercises I could do?
It would be cool to know where I could start and then to have an idea of where to go from there.

If my question is too generic please let me know what other details I could give to make my question better.